# Contacts like ListView

Tags: android, listview

I tried to develop an like contacts ListView for my own listview, for do that I develop an activity with an ListView which use an my owm Adapter.

This adapter extends BaseAdapter and implements SectionIndexer, and I have got this result:

[image: My result]

But I would like have a result like this (this screenshot was captured on a Samsung Galaxy S):

[image: Samsung Galaxy S]

Someone could give me the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what specifically about the second image do you want to implement in your application?

Comment: **Check the `Array(Overlay)` example in your API Demos Sample example. It might be `View/List/9.Array(Overlay)`**

Comment: the alphabet index present on the right.

Comment: Vikas  i saw there but the list example stops at number 8! What it is wrong?http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html

Comment: Not in online API Demo, check in your `android-sdk-windows\samples\android-9\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view\List9.java`. Here I am using Android 2.3 that's why  the path has `android-9` which may different in your case. **Note : you can not run that directly. You need to create a new Android project by choosing the option `Create project from the existing sources` and choose `ApiDemoes`, Now run it and follow my instruction as in my first comment.**  `One more : if you write a comment then use @ symbol followed by the name of the person you want to notify. like @Vikas`

Comment: @pedr0 have you got any solution?

Comment: @pedr0 can you please share your code for this implementation? Here, I need the seperator and side selection list.  Thanks.